# Merging four stored procedures into one

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call 3 other stored procedures within a "master" stored procedure and then return the combined results for all 4 stored procedures.

Is this possible?

And if so, I would appreciate some example sql code. The only way I could see this working is if the "master" stored procedure could somehow store the 3 partial result sets it obtains from the other stored procedures in variables. I'd appreciate the help on this!

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? Stored Procedures only return integers.

Comment: do you have some psuedo code?  Do the stored procs relate to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to join the output of the child procedures together, and that the child procedures return resultsets using `SELECT` statements, this should just work without you needing to do any additional storing of result sets.

Basic example:

```
CREATE PROC up_sample
AS
    EXEC up_proc1

    EXEC up_proc2

    EXEC up_proc3
GO
```